# Calculate row wise proportions by column name in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a numeric data frame and would like to calculate row wise proportions by column name but cannot figure this out

My data looks like:

```
A1  B1  A2  B2
1   2   3   3
```

I would like to transform the dataframe into this:

```
A1  B1  A2  B2
.25 .2  .75 .6
```

i.e the new values are the row wise proportions determined by their column names

Comment: can you explain the proportions? like how is `B1` = 0.2 ?

Answer (score 2):

If I get your question correctly, here's how you could do it

---

Considering this example `DataFrame`

```
val df: DataFrame = spark.createDataFrame(
  rowRDD = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(
    Row(1, 10, 100, 2, 20, 3),
    Row(2, 20, 200, 4, 40, 6)
  )),
  schema = StructType(List(
    StructField("A1", IntegerType, true),
    StructField("B1", IntegerType, true),
    StructField("C1", IntegerType, true),
    StructField("A2", IntegerType, true),
    StructField("B2", IntegerType, true),
    StructField("A3", IntegerType, true)
  ))
)
```

> ```
> +---+---+---+---+---+---+
> | A1| B1| C1| A2| B2| A3|
> +---+---+---+---+---+---+
> |  1| 10|100|  2| 20|  3|
> |  2| 20|200|  4| 40|  6|
> +---+---+---+---+---+---+
> ```

And this list of column-prefixes

```
val columnNamePrefixes: Seq[String] = Seq("A", "B", "C")
```

---

**1. Find names of columns matching given prefixes**

```
def getColumnNameGroups(df: DataFrame, columnNamePrefixes: Seq[String]): Map[String, Seq[String]] = {
  columnNamePrefixes.foldLeft(Map.empty[String, Seq[String]]) { (colNameGroupsMod: Map[String, Seq[String]], colNamePrefix: String) =>
    val colNames: Seq[String] = df.columns.
      toList.
      filter(_.startsWith(colNamePrefix))
    colNameGroupsMod + (colNamePrefix -> colNames)
  }
}
```

> ```
> (A -> List(A1, A2, A3))
> (B -> List(B1, B2))
> (C -> List(C1))
> ```

---

**2. Create sum columns by adding all columns starting with same prefix**

```
def addSumColumns(df: DataFrame, colNameGroups: Map[String, Seq[String]]): DataFrame = {
  colNameGroups.foldLeft(df) { (modDf: DataFrame, tup: (String, Seq[String])) =>
    val sumColName: String = s"${tup._1}_sum"
    val columnsToSum: Seq[Column] = tup._2.map(df(_))

    val modDfSum: DataFrame = modDf.withColumn(sumColName, columnsToSum.reduce(_ + _))
    modDfSum
  }
}
```

> ```
> +---+---+---+---+---+---+-----+-----+-----+
> | A1| B1| C1| A2| B2| A3|A_sum|B_sum|C_sum|
> +---+---+---+---+---+---+-----+-----+-----+
> |  1| 10|100|  2| 20|  3|    6|   30|  100|
> |  2| 20|200|  4| 40|  6|   12|   60|  200|
> +---+---+---+---+---+---+-----+-----+-----+
> ```

---

**3. Convert columns to their ratios by dividing them with sum column**

```
def convertToRatioColumns(df: DataFrame, colNameGroups: Map[String, Seq[String]]): DataFrame = {
  colNameGroups.foldLeft(df) { (modDf: DataFrame, tup: (String, Seq[String])) =>
    val sumColName: String = s"${tup._1}_sum"

    val modDfSum: DataFrame = tup._2.foldLeft(modDf) { (modDfTmp: DataFrame, colName: String) =>
      modDfTmp.withColumn(colName, modDfTmp(colName).divide(modDfTmp(sumColName)))
    }
    modDfSum
  }
}
```

> ```
> +--------+-------+---+-------+-------+---+-----+-----+-----+
> |      A1|     B1| C1|     A2|     B2| A3|A_sum|B_sum|C_sum|
> +--------+-------+---+-------+-------+---+-----+-----+-----+
> |0.166666|0.33333|1.0|0.33333|0.66666|0.5|    6|   30|  100|
> |0.166666|0.33333|1.0|0.33333|0.66666|0.5|   12|   60|  200|
> +--------+-------+---+-------+-------+---+-----+-----+-----+
> ```

---

**4. Drop the sum columns**

```
def dropSumColumns(df: DataFrame, colNameGroups: Map[String, Seq[String]]): DataFrame = {
  colNameGroups.foldLeft(df) { (modDf: DataFrame, tup: (String, Seq[String])) =>
    val sumColName: String = s"${tup._1}_sum"
    modDf.drop(sumColName)
  }
}
```

> ```
> +--------+-------+---+-------+-------+---+
> |      A1|     B1| C1|     A2|     B2| A3|
> +--------+-------+---+-------+-------+---+
> |0.166666|0.33333|1.0|0.33333|0.66666|0.5|
> |0.166666|0.33333|1.0|0.33333|0.66666|0.5|
> +--------+-------+---+-------+-------+---+
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Let’s call the data frame `df`.

You can use `df.schema.fieldNames` to get a list of the column names that need to be computed.

Then use `df.withColumn(colName, expr)` to change the value based on the fieldName for each field. This will probably require multiple calls to df.withColumn and you can do this recursively to chain the operation.

You could also use `.map` which might be even simpler.

Answer (score 0):

well you can do this way :)

```
    val source_DF = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(List((1,2,3,3))).toDF("A1","B1","A2","B2")

    val sum_DF = source_DF.withColumn("SUM", source_DF.columns.map(c => col(c)).reduce((c1, c2) => c1 + c2))

    val proportions_DF = sum_DF.withColumn("A1", col("A1").divide(col("SUM")))
                               .withColumn("B1", col("B1").divide(col("SUM")))
                               .withColumn("A2", col("A2").divide(col("SUM")))
                               .withColumn("B2", col("B2").divide(col("SUM")))
    val Result_DF = proportions_DF.drop("SUM").show()

+-------------------+-------------------+------------------+------------------+
|                 A1|                 B1|                A2|                B2|
+-------------------+-------------------+------------------+------------------+
| 0.1111111111111111| 0.2222222222222222|0.3333333333333333|0.3333333333333333|
```